# semantic mediawiki template query issue

Tags: semantic-mediawiki

I have inherited a template and I am trying to extend it. The template
has a query like this:

```
[[IsSubjectOf::<q>[[-IsTargetOf::<q>[[HasReferenceDataset::SomeReferenceDataSet]]</q>]]</q>]]
```

This returns the subjects in the targets that are in the specified
ReferenceDataset.

Now we have a new type, ResultSet. A result set contains 1 or more
ReferenceDatasets. I want to add one more level of subquery to get the
subjects in the targets that are in ReferenceDatasets in the specified
ResultSet. I tried this (along with 100 other things):

```
[[IsSubjectOf::<q>[[-IsTargetOf::<q>[[IsReferenceDatasetOf::<q>[[HasResponseSet::SomeResponseSet]]</q>]]</q>]]</q>]]
```

But I get nothing back.

```
[[HasResponseSet::SomeResponseSet]]
```

Does return the ReferenceDatasets in the ResponseSet, but

```
[[IsReferenceDatasetOf::<q>[[HasResponseSet::SomeResponseSet]]</q>]]
```

returns nothing. Anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Also what is the meaning of the leading `-` in front of IsTargetOf?

Comment: `-` means implicit inverse property. `-IsTargetOf` is *`IsTagretedBy`. See this: https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Inverse_properties. Inserting a minus before `IsReferenceDatasetOf` might help you.

Comment: Mage sure that `$smwgQMaxDepth` setting is big enough (https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:$smwgQMaxDepth). Also, consider using the dot syntax: https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Subqueries_and_property_chains.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I don't think smwgQMaxDepth is a factor as `[[IsReferenceDatasetOf::<q>[[HasResponseSet::SomeResponseSet]]</q>]]` doesn't return anything. Also tried -IsReferenceDatasetOf - no joy